# Proper time and 4-velocity

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, velocity, inertial-frames

Now, 4-velocity is defined as $\mathbf u^\mu$ = $dx^\mu/d\tau$, $\tau$ being the proper time.
And then the four momenta is $\mathbf P^\mu$= $m_0$$\mathbf u^\mu$.

My doubt is, suppose we have two observers $A$ and $B$, $A$ at rest and $B$ moving with velocity $\mathbf v$ relative to $A$.
Let's suppose, an object $C$ is at rest with respect to $A$.
Then how will $A$ describe $\mathbf u^\mu$ of $C$ ?

$\mathbf u^1$ = $dx^\mu/d\tau$ = $dx/d\tau$... $eq$$\mathbf 1$

And how will $B$ describe $\mathbf u^\mu$ of $C$?.

$
\mathbf u^1$ = $dx'^\mu/d\tau$ = $dx'/d\tau$...$eq$$\mathbf 2$.

What is $\tau$ in $eq $$\mathbf 1$ and $eq $$\mathbf 2$?.

Is $\tau$ the proper time of the object (which will be invariant for any FoR) or is $\tau$ the proper time of the observer ($A$/$B$ depending on who's observing), which is measuring the 4-velocity of the object?

EDIT: Well, if $\tau$ is of the object, that means the 4-velocity of an object measured from observer A will be $dx^\mu/d\tau$ where $\tau$ is the proper time of the object. BUT this also means the the velocity of the object measured with respect to the same observer will be $dx/dt$ where t is the time measured according to the observer, not the object. So does that mean that velocity is not the same as 4-velocity?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-velocity): “the proper time of the object”

Comment: Proper time means the 'proper time of the object'. This is measured in the object's reference frame, no matter who is the observer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, velocity is not the same as 4-velocity. And even the connection between them is not entirely direct. 4-velocity is more directly related not to velocity, but to momentum. Namely, the 4-velocity is an absolute quantity, the 4-vector, which is not tied to a specific reference frame, and its spatial projection — which is already a relative quantity depending on the reference frame — is $\frac 1 m \mathbf p = \frac {\mathbf v} {\sqrt{ 1 - v^2/c^2 }}$.

Comment: Then the 4-velocity of an object, measured according to the observer is the real $'velocity'$?

Comment: 4-velocity is a 4-vector. You cannot measure vectors (3d or 4d), you can only measure the components of a vector. The 4-vector does not depend on the observer, but the components of the 4-vector do. If the observer has a timer and wants to know the distance that the body will travel in some time according to this timer, he needs to use the usual velocity. In this sense, ordinar velocity is a real velocity.

Comment: But if, for example, a moving body is a human, and the observer is interested what distance this human travel when he grows old by 50 years, then the observer will need to use the spatial projection of the 4-velocity, because a person ages according to his own time, proper time, and 4-velocity is a velocity related with the proper time.

Comment: So that means velocity is relative and can be measured in any frame, however, the components of 4-velocity is only measured with respect to the moving body's time.

Comment: Yes, to measure 4-velocity components you need a timer, attached to a moving body and showing its proper time.

Answer (score 0):

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-velocity) explains,

> If the object has mass, so that its speed is necessarily less than the speed of light, the world line may be parametrized by the proper time **of the object**. The four-velocity is the rate of change of four-position with respect to the proper time along the curve.

Comment: Well, that means the 4-velocity of an object measured from observer A will be $dx^\mu/d\tau$ where $\tau$ is the proper time of the object. BUT this also means the the velocity of the object measured with respect to the same observer will be $dx/dt$ where t is the time measured according to the observer, not the object. So does that mean that velocity is not the same as 4-velocity?

Comment: Yes, it means that the three spatial components of the four-velocity are *not* the non-relativistic three-velocity. See [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-velocity#Components_of_the_four-velocity) of the Wikipedia article for their relationship. The four-velocity has a $\gamma$ factor.